# Javascript get updated link in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, javascript-injection

I'm new to javascript and I've created a kinda successful extension on chrome for dubtrack I've been trying to figure out for quite awhile how to make my injected script run in real time and grab the latest youtube music video url any help would be much appreciated my extension is very basic and it's not for profit I just made it to play around with javascript and jquery.

Here's the section of code that I'd like to have function in real time.

```
$('#grab').click(function() {

    function getId(url) {
        var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        var match = url.match(regExp);

        if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
            return match[2];
        } else {
            return 'error';
        }
    }

    src = $('iframe').attr('src');

    setInterval(function() { 
        src = $('iframe').attr('src');
    }, 10000);

    window.open('http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + getId(src), '_blank');
});
```

Relevant links
[GitHub](https://github.com/LordHazious/DTplugin/blob/master/DTplugin.js)
[Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dubtrack-plugin/pmhgeigfpnffakmfcbkmhnapmkmcpmnj)

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly? You want to know how to run something "in real time?" Or you want to know how to grab things from YouTube "in real time?" Also, please go into detail by what you mean by "in real time."

Comment: dubtrack is a website that allows people to dj and play youtube music video's I can currently grab the first video that was playing when the page loaded but it wont update from the first video unless i refresh the page.

Comment: Meaning, you need to refresh dubtrack or youtube?

Comment: there is a div with id player... you could try to link an event to the player in it and when player is [ended](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) read the new url... [this could help you too](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You're bad at explaining (and might want to edit the question to reflect what you want), but basically the problem is this:

1. You have a YouTube embed in the page, with a particular video ID in `src`.
2. When the video changes, that happens without updating the `src` (by using YT embed API).
3. Therefore, if you try to grab just the `src`, it's not the latest video but the first you loaded.

As an extension, I see two ways of trying to solve it:

1. You could try to initialize the [YT API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) *yourself* to get a `player` reference. I don't know if it will break the code of Dubtrack.
2. You could inject a script in the iframe as well that would somehow extract the video being played in a way other than relying on `src`.

It's an open problem how to solve it, and the fact that you're basically providing "just" a bookmarklet may be an obstacle.